# read system call doesn't detect end of file

Tags: c, string, posix, c-strings

I'm trying to create a function that reads an entire file using a specific read size that can change anytime, but the read system call doesn't store the characters properly in the buffer, so far I'm only trying to print until the end of file like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

# define READ_SIZE (42)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   int fd;
   int rd;
   char *buffer;

   buffer = malloc(READ_SIZE);
   fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
   while ((rd = read(fd, buffer, READ_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
       printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    return (0);
 }
```

This is the file that I'm trying to read:

```
test1234
test123
test1
test2
test3
test4
test
```

This is the output of my program:

```
test123
test12
test1
test2
test3
test4
testest123
test12
test1
test2
test3
test4
tes
```

I can only use `malloc`, and read to handle this, open is only for testing, and I don't understand why it does this, usually read returns the number of bytes read in that file, and 0 if it reaches the end of file, so it's a bit weird to see this.

Comment: Your program is invalid and will not compile, as a result of unbalanced parentheses in your `while()` statement.  Where you put the missing parenthesis will affect the meaning of your code.

Comment: It is also missing `#include` statements. Please provide a _complete_ and _compilable_ example.

Comment: You forgot to `NULL` terminate the buffer before using `printf`

Comment: my apologies, I've changed the code now to compile and work properly

Comment: @user161151 `NULL` is the _null pointer constant_.  Certainly you mean the _null character_ or `'\0'`.

Comment: @chux I certainly do.

Comment: @James If your new code has the same issue as this (printing a  character array lacking a null character with `%s`) then the new code is also caught in the _Undefined Behavior_ (UB) trap.  It may work today and fail tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the very elegant solution provided by [*chux*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41641808/694576) you could as well just terminate the buffer (and with this only make it a C-"string") explicitly before printing:

```
while ((rd = read(fd, buffer, READ_SIZE-1)) > 0) /* read one less, to have a spare 
                                                    char available for the `0`-terminator. */
{
  buffer[rd] = '\0';
  printf("'%s'", buffer);
}
```

Comment: Suggest this [fine advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641557/read-system-call-doesnt-detect-end-of-file/41641808#comment70484133_41641808)  It comes from a reliable source.

Comment: @chux: Adapted! :))

Comment: the result is better than what it was, but i understand how it works now i'll see how to fix it, thanks guys ^_^

Comment: BTW, using a debugger (mostly) helps a lot in identifying  root causes of "weird" behaviour.... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The printing of the character array lacks a null character.  This is UB with `"%s"`.

```
printf("%s", buffer);  // bad
```

To limit printing a character array lacking a null character, use a precision modifier.  This will print the character array up to that many characters or a null character - which ever is first.

```
// printf("%s", buffer);
printf("%.*s", rd, buffer);
```

---

Debug tip: Print text with sentinels to clearly indicate the result of each print.

```
printf("<%.*s>\n", rd, buffer);
```

Comment: it prints the characters correctly yes, but how can i implement this in storing the characters in another buffer, to contain all the characters within the file.

Comment: @James This answer is for the current question with its "so far i'm only trying to print until the end of file like this,"  and "and i don't understand why it does this".  Your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641557/read-system-call-doesnt-detect-end-of-file/41641808#comment70483602_41641808) is asking anew question better suited as a new post.  One question at a time.

Comment: "*Debug tip: Print text with sentinels*" yes, yes, my speech since ages! :-) +++1

Comment: fair enough ^_^ thanks for the help i'll search more and if i don't make any progress i'll post again